# Weird error on a Report while running

Tags: xml, reporting-services

when I run a certain report I get a "there is an error in xml document (1,25063)
' ', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. line 1 position  25063" error.

I do not get the error on my pc, but 2 other users do when they run the report on reportserver.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks as if there's a x1F character at position 25063 in your file. Which would certainly make it unable to parse as XML.

The most likely reason for this kind of problem is that the file is not in the encoding that the XML parser thinks it's in.

And there are two reasons for that: either the person creating the file labelled it with the wrong encoding, or the encoding got changed in transit.

You're going to have to do some detective work. Use a hex editor to find non-ASCII bytes (hex values greater than 7F. Try to work out from the context what they represent. From that you should be able to discover the encoding of the file. Compare this with the encoding given in the XML declaration.

Then, when you discover there's a mismatch, trace back the history of the file to find out where and when it got corrupted; from that work out how, and how to stop it happening again.

Comment: No, the error was because the link did not have the command render, does anyone know why this happened?